# "The method addAttribute(Class<CharTermAttribute>) is undefined for the type TokenStream" while using Apache Lucene in Java

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize, stringtokenizer, analyzer

I am using `Apache Lucene` for tokenizing string in Java and I am encountering the below error even after importing all the external jar files.

***The error is:***

The method addAttribute(Class) is undefined for the type TokenStream

***The line of code in which the error occured:***

CharTermAttribute charTermAttri=stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

***The code is:***

```
public static ArrayList<String> tokenizeString(Analyzer analyzer, String string) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
          TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream(null, new StringReader(string));
          **CharTermAttribute charTermAttri = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);**
          stream.reset();
          while (stream.incrementToken()) {
            result.add(stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString());
          }
          stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // not thrown b/c we're using a string reader...
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return result;
      }
```

Comment: Can you show us the import statements? Whenever someone posts an incomplete example, the trouble is in the part they didn't post.